# filter function - how to check if the id of an item matches any id in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a list of 'items' and each 'item' has an 'id'. I also have a list of 'ids'. I would like to filter down my list of 'items' so that each item in my list must also match any 'id' in my list of 'ids'.

**I basically want to filter out all items that do not have a corresponding id in my list of ids.**

This is what I was trying, I am not sure how to check each id in my list of ids in this filter function.

```
items = items.filter(item => item.id !== itemIds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
items = items.filter(item => !itemIds.includes(item.id))
```

Comment: Ive realized itemIds comes from my store... its a const of unknowns and does not have a 'includes' function. Is there a more general solution? ```itemIds.includes is not a function. (In ItemIds.includes(item.id), itemIds.includes is undefined)```

Comment: You didn't mention that you are using TypeScript. `unknown` types are means to be mapped using for example `as`. `itemIds as string[]`. Or you should probably type your store in some way.

Comment: hmmm I am not following... do you think you could update your answer to reflect your comment? I would rather not have to do it in my store if possible.

Comment: What is `itemIds` because it's not an array if it doesn't have the `includes` method (unless you're using a browser over 7 years old...)